# Why do some springform pans have bumps all over the bottom piece?

Tags: equipment, pan

Some springform pans have a perfectly flat bottom piece, but other springform pans have a bottom piece with bumps all over it, such as this one:

[image]

Do the bumps serve any purpose? I have never used a springform pan before, but I would imagine the bumps might make it more difficult to completely slice all the way through a cheesecake, resulting in a lot of crumbs breaking off the crust as you try to remove a slice of cheesecake from the bottom piece. I would imagine that fewer crumbs would break off the crust if the bottom piece was flat.

Comment: I've been using these sort of pans *forever*, and it's never resulted in crumbs breaking off.  The bumps are probably also a way of strengthening the base sheet-metal.

Comment: As Kingsley suggested, both working the metal (deforming it while it’s solid) and a waffle-like structure will stiffen it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Bustle](https://www.bustle.com/life/the-4-best-springform-pans-22622670), the purpose of the texture is to ensure even baking:

> Some springform pans feature textured bases, which provide more even air and heat distribution while baking.

Clearly, though, many manufacturers do not agree that this is a real advantage.

I recommend always lining the bottom of the pan with a circle of parchment paper regardless of whether or not the recipe calls for it.  This not only ensures clean release, it also prevents you from scratching the pan if you cut the cake while it's still on the pan base.